# Custom templates folder

Tags: templates

I created a custom folder ("/templates") and I put all of my template files in the folder. instead of root ("/wp-content/themes/my-theme/"). It works fine.

Do I have to add some function for indicating "/templates/" folder as my templates folder?
Usually you put them on root, right?

It works fine now but I just wonder if there is anything I have to. I can't find any information on wordpress codex.
I just installed WPML and All of templates pages are 404 now. I wonder if it(custom template folder location) causes this 404 pages. cuz woo-commerce pages are showing fine. wc is not in my template folder. it generated by plugin.

-------- Additional

I created a template 
www/wp-content/themes/my-theme/tpl-home.php

I named this file as a template page.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
get_header(); ?>
```

And I moved templates files on www/wp-content/themes/my-theme/templates/tpl-home.php

It still works well. I have seen a lot of themes do like this.

Do I need to setup some function to indicated the folder?

Comment: what you mean by root? root of what? `themes=>your-theme` your currently active theme root?

Comment: Thanks guys. I added more information. please let me know if you need more. Root means. theme root.. so /wp-content/themes/my-theme/

Comment: Are you referring to WordPress Template Hierarchy template files, or *custom page templates*?

Comment: Sorry, why? What does this accomplish that the Core functions and methods can not?

Answer (score 11):

As of [WordPress 3.4](https://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/) you can put your page templates in whatever **direct subdirectory** you need, it doesn't sound like you can put them into sub-sub directories but I haven't tested this.

I suggest storing templates into `/page-templates/` folder as WordPress seems to recognize it. From [WordPress Page Templates Entry:](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#file-organization-of-page-templates)

> WordPress recognizes the subfolder `page-templates`. Therefore, it’s a good idea to store your global page templates in this folder to help keep them organized.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your templates within your active theme where ever you want but you have to include your files to functions.php.

You can make a folder called `page-templates` within your current theme.

`/wp-content/themes/my-theme/page-templates`

and add your custom templates there.

Include files in `functions.php`

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/my-template.php' ) ) {
    include_once 'page-templates/my-template.php';
}
```

it should work.

Comment: doesn't work at all for me

Comment: Great. THis is working fully for me.